# To Do List Delete Button within HTML <li> element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, jquery-selectors

I am trying to get a delete button working on my To Do List project. I have tried a lot of different things but I am not having any luck. I believe the issue stems from the fact that I am trying to reference a button in an HTML li tag that is created by Javascript/jQuery when a user enters a new task in the To Do List. I probably am messing up the syntax relation between the two. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks ahead of time.

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Project 4 - To Do List</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page">
            <h1 id="header"></h1>
            <h2>To Do List <span id="counter"></span></h2>
            <h3>"If you can dream it, you can do it" - Walt Disney</h3>
            <div id="newItemButton"><button href="#" id="showForm">New Entry</button></div>
            <form id="newItemForm">
                <input type="text" id="itemDescription" placeholder="Enter goal" />
                <input type="submit" id="add" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
            <ul>
                <!--<li id="one">Exercise</li>
                <li id="two">Study</li>
                <li id="three">Practice a New Language</li>
                <li id="four">Work on Personal Project</li>-->
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="about">
            <a id="link" href="x">About</a>
        </div>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
        <script src="javascript_jquery.js"></script>
    </body>
    <footer>
        <div id="footer">To do List Icons made by <a id="link" href="http://www.freepik.com" title="Freepik">Freepik</a> from <a id="link" href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon">www.flaticon.com</a> is licensed by <a id="link" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/" title="Creative Commons BY 3.0" target="_blank">CC 3.0 BY</a>
        </div>
        <div id="footer">Trash Icons made by <a id="link" href="https://www.flaticon.com/authors/dave-gandy" title="Dave Gandy">Dave Gandy</a> from <a id="link" href="https://www.flaticon.com/" title="Flaticon">www.flaticon.com</a> is licensed by <a id="link" href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/" title="Creative Commons BY 3.0" target="_blank">CC 3.0 BY</a></div>
    </footer>
</html>
```

Here is the Javascript/jQuery. The focus of my issue is on the Delete function at the bottom and probably the .append part under "Check as Complete."

```
/*eslint-env jquery*/
/* eslint-env browser */

$(document).ready(function() {

    // SETUP
    var $list, $newItemForm, $newItemButton;
    var item = '';                                 // item is an empty string
    $list = $('ul');                               // Cache the unordered list
    $newItemForm = $('#newItemForm');              // Cache form to add new items
    $newItemButton = $('#newItemButton');          // Cache button to show form

    // ITEM COUNTER
    function updateCount() {                       // Create function to update counter
        var items = $('li[class!=complete]').length; // Number of items in list
        $('#counter').text(items);                   // Added into counter circle
    }
    updateCount();                                 // Call the function

    // SETUP FORM FOR NEW ITEMS
    $newItemButton.show();                         // Show the button
    $newItemForm.hide();                           // Hide the form
    $('#showForm').on('click', function() {        // When click on add item button
        $newItemButton.hide();                       // Hide the button
        $newItemForm.show();                         // Show the form
    });

    // ADDING A NEW LIST ITEM
    $newItemForm.on('submit', function(e) {       // When a new item is submitted
        e.preventDefault();                         // Prevent form being submitted
        var text = $('input:text').val();           // Get value of text input
        $list.append('<li>' + text + '</li>');      // Add item to end of the list
        $('input:text').val('');                    // Empty the text input
        updateCount();                              // Update the count
    });

    //Check as Complete
    $list.on('click', 'li', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var complete = $this.hasClass('complete');

        if (complete !== true) {
            item = $this.text();             // Get the text from the list item
            $this.remove();                  // Remove the list item
            $list                            // Add back to end of list as complete
                .append('<li class=\"complete\">' + item + '<button type="button" class="trashbutton" src="/images/icon-trash.png" alt="Trash Icon"></button>' + '</li>')
                .hide().fadeIn(300);           // Hide it so it can be faded in
            complete = true;
        }
        updateCount();
    });

    /*//Check as Incomplete
    $list.on('click', 'li', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var complete = $this.hasClass('complete'); 

        if (complete === true) {
            item = $this.text();
            $this.remove();
            $list
                .append('<li>' + item + '</li>')
                .hide().fadeIn(300);
        }
        updateCount();
    });*/

    // Delete
    $list.on('click', 'li', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var readyToDelete = $this.hasClass('trashbutton');

        if(readyToDelete === true) {
            $this.animate({                
                opacity: 0.0,
                paddingLeft: '+=180'
            }, 500, 'swing', function() {
                $this.remove();
            });
        }
        updateCount;
    }); 
});
```

Here is the CSS just in case.

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);

body {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    font-family: 'Oswald', 'Futura', sans-serif;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

#page {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Responsive page rules at bottom of style sheet */

h1 {
    background-image: url('/images/icon.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: -1000%;
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 75px;
    width: 117px;
    margin: auto auto auto auto;
    padding: 30px 10px 20px 10px;
}

h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .3em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 23px 0;
}

h2 span {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: green;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: -5px;
    height: 22px;
    width: 26px;
    padding: 4px 0 0 0;
}

h3 {
    color: white;
}

ul {
    border:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    color: black;
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    font-size: 24px;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px grey;
    text-align: left;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

/* unvisited link */
#link:link {
    color: yellowgreen;
}

/* visited link */
#link:visited {
    color: green;
}

/* mouse over link */
#link:hover {
    color: darkseagreen;
}

/* selected link */
#link:active {
    color: forestgreen;
}

.about {
    text-align: center;
}

#footer {
    background:none;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

.complete {
    background-color: #999;
    color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #333;
}

.trashbutton {
    background-image: url('/images/icon-trash.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 12px 12px;
    margin: auto !important;
    position: relative;
    top: 35%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);

}

/* FORM STYLES */

form {
    padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
}

input[type='text'], input[type='password'], textarea {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 96%;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 8px;}

input[type='submit'], a.add, button, a.show {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: none;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', 'Futura', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px grey;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;}

input[type='submit'], button {
    float: right;
} 

input[type='submit']:hover {
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* form example */
#newItemButton {
    padding: 10px 20px 75px 20px;
    display: none;
}

#newItemForm {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#itemDescription {
    width: 325px;
}

#newItemForm input[type='submit'] {
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Attributes example */
#group {
    margin: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}

/* Small screen:mobile */
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background-color: #403c3b;
    }
    #page {
        max-width: 480px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    #page {
        max-width: 480px;
        margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
    #page {
        max-width: 480px;
        margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    }
}

/* Larger screens act like a demo for the app */
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    #page {
        max-width: 480px;
        margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    }
}

@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    h1{
        background-image: url('/images/icon.png');
        background-size: 100px 100px;
    }
}
```

Some screenshots of what works so far. You can see the tasks as incomplete in green, completed in grey, and the trash button shows up when the task is grey.

[When app first loads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBW0H.png)

[One incomplete task and one complete task. Notice trash button that does not work.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PA4U.png)

NOTE: I should mention that, while heavily altered, the HTML and JS code is derived from an example from Jon Duckett's Javascript and jQuery book. This is my first time ever working with jQuery and the purpose of this assignment is to learn the basics.

Comment: You’re using a really old version of jQuery. You should consider downloaded a newer version.

Comment: You are right. I went ahead and downloaded a newer version. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can get it working:

1. Change `$list.on('click', 'li', function() {` to `$list.on('click', 'li > button', function() {` (your list items doesn't have 'trashbutton' class).
2. Update code you use to delete element since after clicking on a button you have to delete parent element (`li`), not the button itself.

Take a look at this in action:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    // SETUP
    var $list, $newItemForm, $newItemButton;
    var item = '';                                 // item is an empty string
    $list = $('ul');                               // Cache the unordered list
    $newItemForm = $('#newItemForm');              // Cache form to add new items
    $newItemButton = $('#newItemButton');          // Cache button to show form

    // ITEM COUNTER
    function updateCount() {                       // Create function to update counter
        var items = $('li[class!=complete]').length; // Number of items in list
        $('#counter').text(items);                   // Added into counter circle
    }
    updateCount();                                 // Call the function

    // SETUP FORM FOR NEW ITEMS
    $newItemButton.show();                         // Show the button
    $newItemForm.hide();                           // Hide the form
    $('#showForm').on('click', function() {        // When click on add item button
        $newItemButton.hide();                       // Hide the button
        $newItemForm.show();                         // Show the form
    });

    // ADDING A NEW LIST ITEM
    $newItemForm.on('submit', function(e) {       // When a new item is submitted
        e.preventDefault();                         // Prevent form being submitted
        var text = $('input:text').val();           // Get value of text input
        $list.append('<li>' + text + '</li>');      // Add item to end of the list
        $('input:text').val('');                    // Empty the text input
        updateCount();                              // Update the count
    });

    //Check as Complete
    $list.on('click', 'li', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var complete = $this.hasClass('complete');

        if (complete !== true) {
            item = $this.text();             // Get the text from the list item
            $this.remove();                  // Remove the list item
            $list                            // Add back to end of list as complete
                .append('<li class=\"complete\">' + item + '<button type="button" class="trashbutton" src="/images/icon-trash.png" alt="Trash Icon"></button>' + '</li>')
                .hide().fadeIn(300);           // Hide it so it can be faded in
            complete = true;
        }
        updateCount();
    });

    /*//Check as Incomplete
    $list.on('click', 'li', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var complete = $this.hasClass('complete'); 

        if (complete === true) {
            item = $this.text();
            $this.remove();
            $list
                .append('<li>' + item + '</li>')
                .hide().fadeIn(300);
        }
        updateCount();
    });*/

    // Delete
    $list.on('click', 'li > button', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var readyToDelete = $this.hasClass('trashbutton');

        if(readyToDelete === true) {
            $this.parent().animate({                
                opacity: 0.0,
                paddingLeft: '+=180'
            }, 500, 'swing', function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });
        }
        updateCount;
    }); 
});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald);

body {
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    font-family: 'Oswald', 'Futura', sans-serif;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0;
}

#page {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}
/* Responsive page rules at bottom of style sheet */

h1 {
    background-image: url('/images/icon.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    text-align: center;
    text-indent: -1000%;
    height: 75px;
    line-height: 75px;
    width: 117px;
    margin: auto auto auto auto;
    padding: 30px 10px 20px 10px;
}

h2 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: .3em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 0 23px 0;
}

h2 span {
    background-color: #fff;
    color: green;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: -5px;
    height: 22px;
    width: 26px;
    padding: 4px 0 0 0;
}

h3 {
    color: white;
}

ul {
    border:none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

li {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    color: black;
    border-top: 1px solid grey;
    border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
    font-size: 24px;
    letter-spacing: .05em;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px grey;
    text-align: left;
    height: 50px;
    padding-left: 1em;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-right: 1em;
}

/* unvisited link */
#link:link {
    color: yellowgreen;
}

/* visited link */
#link:visited {
    color: green;
}

/* mouse over link */
#link:hover {
    color: darkseagreen;
}

/* selected link */
#link:active {
    color: forestgreen;
}

.about {
    text-align: center;
}

#footer {
    background:none;
    color: black;
    text-align: center;
}

.complete {
    background-color: #999;
    color: white;
    border-top: 1px solid #666;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #b0b0b0;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px #333;
}

.trashbutton {
    background-image: url('/images/icon-trash.png');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 12px 12px;
    margin: auto !important;
    position: relative;
    top: 35%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);

}

/* FORM STYLES */

form {
    padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
}

input[type='text'], input[type='password'], textarea {
  background-color: whitesmoke;
  color: black;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 96%;
  padding: 4px 6px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  border-radius: 8px;}

input[type='submit'], a.add, button, a.show {
    background-color: yellowgreen;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border: none;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', 'Futura', sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px grey;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;}

input[type='submit'], button {
    float: right;
} 

input[type='submit']:hover {
    background-color: green;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* form example */
#newItemButton {
    padding: 10px 20px 75px 20px;
    display: none;
}

#newItemForm {
    padding-top: 20px;
}

#itemDescription {
    width: 325px;
}

#newItemForm input[type='submit'] {
    margin-top: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Attributes example */
#group {
    margin: 10px;
    border: 2px solid #fff;
}

/* Small screen:mobile */
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    body {
        background-color: #403c3b;
    }
    #page {
        max-width: 480px;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 501px) and (max-width: 767px) {
    #page {
        max-width: 480px;
        margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px) {
    #page {
        max-width: 480px;
        margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    }
}

/* Larger screens act like a demo for the app */
@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) {
    #page {
        max-width: 480px;
        margin: 20px auto 20px auto;
    }
}

@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), (min-resolution: 192dpi) { 
    h1{
        background-image: url('/images/icon.png');
        background-size: 100px 100px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="page">
            <h1 id="header"></h1>
            <h2>To Do List <span id="counter"></span></h2>
            <h3>"If you can dream it, you can do it" - Walt Disney</h3>
            <div id="newItemButton"><button href="#" id="showForm">New Entry</button></div>
            <form id="newItemForm">
                <input type="text" id="itemDescription" placeholder="Enter goal" />
                <input type="submit" id="add" value="Submit"/>
            </form>
            <ul>
                <!--<li id="one">Exercise</li>
                <li id="two">Study</li>
                <li id="three">Practice a New Language</li>
                <li id="four">Work on Personal Project</li>-->
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="about">
            <a id="link" href="x">About</a>
        </div>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
        <script src="javascript_jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you Andrey. This works and it made sense to me after I looked up documentation about the ">" syntax you provided. Just one thing, now that the delete function works when I uncommented the "Check as Incomplete" section I have a bug where clicking the trash button is the same as clicking anywhere else on the item and just sets it as incomplete instead of deleting it. Any chance you have some input about this bug?

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier for you to accomplish your task by giving the trashbutton class a click event to remove its parent li from the list. This can be accomplished with the following code.

```
  // Delete
    $('.trashbutton').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $(this).parent().animate({                
            opacity: 0.0,
            paddingLeft: '+=180'
        }, 500, 'swing', function() {
                $(this).parent().remove();
            });
        }
        updateCount();
    })
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not work for me. I had tried one or two parent() implementations before posting this question but nothing worked. Thank you though.